Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources' @rnmapbox/maps
When i was installing @rnmapbox/maps, i followed all procedures but i got this error
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.


Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not resolve com.mapbox.maps:android:11.0.0.
Required by:
project :app > project :rnmapbox_maps
> Could not resolve com.mapbox.maps:android:11.0.0.
> Could not get resource 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven/com/mapbox/maps/android/11.0.0/android-11.0.0.pom'.
> Could not GET 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven/com/mapbox/maps/android/11.0.0/android-11.0.0.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
Could not resolve com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-turf:6.11.0.
Required by:
project :app > project :rnmapbox_maps
> Could not resolve com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-sdk-turf:6.11.0.
> Could not get resource 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-sdk-turf/6.11.0/mapbox-sdk-turf-6.11.0.pom'.
> Could not GET 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-sdk-turf/6.11.0/mapbox-sdk-turf-6.11.0.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

I am tring to include mapbox in expo react native application

i was able to solve it when i build it using EAS build

"Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized".
Put your token to app.json. Like this:
{"expo": {
"plugins": [[
    "expo-location",
    {
      "locationWhenInUsePermission": "Show current location on map."
    }
  ],
  [
    "@rnmapbox/maps",
    {
      "RNMapboxMapsVersion": "11.0.0",
      "RNMapboxMapsDownloadToken": "sk.ey.."
    }
  ]
]}}


i have put it the same results

@GodwinNamweli You can create a example repo. I will take a look.

Make sure your MapBox access token is configured with the right "scopes". I couldn't say which ones you need exactly, but I was able to reproduce and fix this quickly locally by creating a token with all permissions. So that seems to be the issue: a token with missing scopes to access all the required resources.
